# Building Flutter iOS binary without physical access to a Mac

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

- I have an iPhone
- I don't have a physical mac. I'm using the new AWS mac instances to use XCode / build the binaries (Completely kosher and allowed by Apple).
- I  can't connect the phone and the AWS instance since they're not physically in the same place.
- If I can build an IPA of the app, I should be able to use Firebase distribution to distribute the app to my phone (I think). But when I try to build the app using `flutter build ios` I get errors like: 'There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it'

What should I do? Can I virtually register my device somehow by putting its UUID somewhere? Can I sign up for a developer account and use TestFlight to distribute the app? Will that also require the device to be physically plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer for the TestFlight part. You can distribute the app via TestFlight, and the device does not have to be plugged in. So that is very doable.

Using TestFlight is simple and pretty straight forward with many guides, official ones and also on youtube. There are several troubleshooting tips here on SO as well. The drawback as I see it is that it takes time before your pushed build is readily available on TestFlight. So it won't be a good way to iterate code changes fast.

Comment: Can you have an internal team which gets builds quickly? Or does that also need a device to be physically plugged in to be registered?

Comment: You can have separate tracks in TestFlight for separate user groups and where they get separate builds. You invite people to those tracks via email lists. I've experienced seconds to days in the span from when a build is uploaded to when it is available for testing. First build always takes longer time. Then things like changing version number will make it take longer time. So it kind of depends on what you change when you push new code.

Comment: If you have a developer account, can you add devices to your account virtually? If so, I think I might be able to build an IPA and use Firebase to get it to my phone